# Uncommenting in a .xml file with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, replace, xml-comments

I'm writing a script that replaces and delete some commented lines but the problem is the .xml file got more than only one thing which is commented and I only have to uncomment one of these. It would be no problem if there's everything written on one line but it's not.

XML looks like this:

```
<!--
<session-config>
    <anything>
</session-config>
-->
<!--
<something-else>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</something-else>
-->
```

So: I need to remove `<!-- and -->` by the `<session-config>`, `</session-config>` but NOT by the `<something-else>`, `</something-else>`!! And if I use `-replace "<!--", ""` it will delete the comment as well by `<something else>` and this is not what I want.

Comment: As long as the replacement is being performed on a single string `-replace '(?s)<!--\s+(.*?<session-config>.*?)-->, '$1'`. That should remove comments and keep the data where "<session-config>" appears in between. [regex link](https://regex101.com/r/zixpbb/1)

Comment: The variable $1 is this the normal one without comments?